# Batch update by "update" query of cqlsh in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I want to do batch update for all rows, using update query. I know there is BATCH query. But, I have to list all rows..

So, I want to do something like :

UPDATE test set value=0x31 where id in ( SELECT id from test );

Is there any way doing something like the above?

The idea is the same as SQL. select all rows & and insert them into "in" part.

The reason why I want to do this is that I added a new column to the existing column family, which created null data in the new created column.
And, this cause an error for retrieving data from Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I think the examples shown here might help: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_g4h_qzq_xj__description_unique_31

Update a column in several rows at once:

UPDATE users
  SET state = 'TX'
  WHERE user_uuid
  IN (88b8fd18-b1ed-4e96-bf79-4280797cba80,
    06a8913c-c0d6-477c-937d-6c1b69a95d43,
    bc108776-7cb5-477f-917d-869c12dfffa8);

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The problem of that approach is that I have to list all possible value, e.g. in this case, all values of user_uuid. Point is how to update "all" columns without listing up all values. if there is a ways by just one command, it is very useful.

Comment: Sorry, not "all" columns. it is all "rows".